# gerrit error "change closed" after in-line edit

Tags: git, gerrit

I have in-lined edited (via the gerrit UI) one patch-set. It was accepted and submitted, thus this change-set has been merged and closed. This change does have some children, which have not been submitted yet. The in-line edit did create a new commit id for this particular change set.

After that, I did pull the submitted change to update my local branch. I needed to `pull --rebase`, since `fast-foward` merge was not possible. The rebase brought me into the commit which was introduced by the in-line edit. I fixed a conflict which was introduced by my in-line eidit, and ran `rebase --continue`. Pushing now my branch to gerrit rejects with the message: `! [remote rejected] HEAD ... (change http://.../93 closed)`, where `http://.../93` is the change-set which I just pulled in.

Yes sure it is closed, since it was submitted and merged into remote. So why wants git to push that pulled in commit to remote.
Or to get straight to the point: how to escape that situation, since there are more than 13 commits (including one merge to another branch) coming after this one.

---

Some more information:

`$ git log
* 7316eba - (HEAD -> feature#93)
* b23274f
* 32ae464
* 2cd68bb
* d485183 - (origin/feature#93)`

Commit `d485183` was introduced by the in-line edit. This commit is the same as the one shown in the gerrit change-set. Commit `2cd68bb` and those above have not been submitted yet. The change-sets belonging to these commits do show a path conflict in gerrit UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question:
Commit `2cd68bb` is the old working state of `d485183`. Thus both are having the same change id. `pull --rebase` has been rebasing my stuff on top of gerrits new commit. I fixed it by dropping commit `2cd68bb`.